# Kingdom Come Deliverance: Hidden Perks?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

So I have heard there are hidden perks you can unlock. Such as one where your strength is increased if you have been gathering herbs. I wonder are there more perks hidden behind certain activities?

A list of hidden perks (and preferably how to acquire them) would be appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify I mean perks that are not known, and once unlocked are shown within the Buffs section of the player menu.

Comment: The strength increase is not a hidden perk. You can train that perk at level 10. But there is a hidden perk with herbalism. If you collect enough nettles you'll unlock a +2 to vitality. Because you gained resistance due to picking poisonous plants. I've also read there is a Cuman-Killer perk you get by killing aprox 35 cumans but I haven't unlocked that one yet so I can't be too sure.

Comment: Arguably, the perks that can't be trained in the character menu but only taught by NPCs could be called hidden. The counterattacks taught by Bernard have been missed by quite a lot of people who then complained about the combat being too hard and there's a few other examples.

Comment: @Pahlavan But if you count perks that can only be taught by npc's then the whole reading skill is a hidden perk?

Answer (score 6):

As stated in comments already (but not as answers), these are hidden perks :

1. Gathering 100 nettles will give you "Resistance", granting you a permanent +2 to Vitality
2. Killing several dozens of Cumans will give you the "Cuman Slayer"
   perk, granting you a +50% bonus to moral damage versus Cumans (i.e.
   they are more likely to flee/surrender)
3. Perfect Block/Master Strikes are taught by Captain Bernard at
   Rattay. You cannot get them in any other (normal) way.
4. Having sex with a bath wench (ask a bathhouse propritary)/Theresa/Lady Stephany/after partying with Father Godwin (one quest for each of them, with sex at the end) will give you the
   "Alpha Male" buff, granting you a temporary +2 to Charisma for 24 or
   48h.

Comment: About 4:  how to having sex ?

Comment: @HahaTTpro https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5whJxOIYk4&t=32s

Comment: Is the 100 nettles perk "Resistance"? I've had it a while and had no idea where it came from...

Comment: @Asinine : Yes, that's the one.

Answer (score 5):

Two quest related perks are missing from the other answer.

You get one Perk on the Quest "The Prey" where you go hunting with Hans Capon, the perk lets you loot game animals you kill without it counting as stolen so all the hares you kill while it's active you can keep and sell legally.

The second perk you get by completing a series of quests by the Huntsman of Talmberg which unlocks after the battle at Pribyslavitz, if you side with Hare you get the option at the end of the questline to become the Huntsman of Talmberg and get a perk with the name of "Henry the Master Huntsman", the perk like the previous one allows you to loot wild animals without it counting as stolen except it is now permanent.