# What perks can be picked up automatically throughout the game?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

While playing *Kingdom Come: Deliverance*, you pick up certain skills along the way.

For example, the '*Dodge*', '*Perfect Block*', and '*Feint*' perks are taught to you by Captain Bernard, '*First Aid I*' and '*Bailman*' seem to be learned automatically when levelling the Main Level and Warfare for the first time respectively, and '*Dodger*' had appeared without notification (although I presume this is also taught by Bernard).

[image: Auto-unlocked perks - screenshot merely providing visual relief]

And then there is '*Resistance*', which seems to be hidden entirely from the character screen until its prerequisite is met.

[image: Yup, I paid my debt to Peshek through selling nettle]

**I am wondering if there is a list of perks that are or can be learned automatically while playing the game, so I can save my points for other perks.**
Are there certain missions or encounters that unlock character perks?

The [Fandom page on perks](https://kingdom-come-deliverance.fandom.com/wiki/Perks) is inconsistent when it comes to mentioning these triggers.

<sup>Note that this question is different from [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/329446/kingdom-come-deliverance-hidden-perks), which asks specifically after hidden perks (like '*Resistance*').</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the perks awarded for quests or other achievements are perks that you can spend points on.

Feel free to invest perk points as you see fit without fear of buying something you will get automatically.